# image thumbnail issue

Tags: image, asp.net-mvc-2, thumbnails

I have developed the site in asp.net MVC 2,  where I am offering the user to upload image for his profile photo. so after browse and upload I am making its thumbnail. but this thumbnail is generating without any quality. means it generates quality less thumbnail. What is the way so that I can get quality thumbnail ?

Answer (score 0):

You may checkout the [following article](http://www.mikeborozdin.com/post/High-Quality-Image-Resizing-with-NET.aspx) which illustrates how to generate high quality resized images using GDI+. And here's another more [comprehensive method](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/imgresizoutperfgdiplus.aspx).

Comment: Thanks this may be helpful for me, but then Is i need to save this thumbnail image in file system or in DB. what will affects if keep it i DB and in file system ?.

Comment: @Lalit, I would keep the thumbnail at the same location as the original image. So if you are storing the original image in the database store the thumbnail as well.

Comment: I tried this Darin , but it not changes the size as provided to the function. any other way ? bytheway I want to get Image object from Request.Files how can i get that?